# Autofill fields form when selected value from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I wish to do the same thing as this tutorial [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/freesolocreateoption-demo-material-ui-forked-oclo3s?file=/demo.js)  but instead of populate every field separately, I wish when I select the first name, the other fields autofill according to the selected value of `first name` from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an event listener on one of the name filelds, which contains one of the names. Call a function to populate the input fields. I hope you 'll find it useful

See code below:

```
<form>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="first_name"
        id="first_name"
        placeholder="First Name"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="last_name"
        id="last_name"
        placeholder="Last Name"
      />
    </form>

    <script>
      //This comes from the ajax request:
      var namesFromDB = ["John Doe", "Ferenc Minta", "Dr. Heinz Doofenshmirtz"];

      //Var init:
      var firstNames = {};
      var lastNames = {};

      //When the doc loads
      $(function () {
        //Loop over the names to split them by whitespace
        $.each(namesFromDB, function (index, val) {
          let nameSplit = val.split(" ");

          //To handle the names or pronunciations. You can extend this further more.
          switch (nameSplit.length) {
            case 3:
              firstNames[index] = nameSplit[0] + " " + nameSplit[1];
              lastNames[index] = nameSplit[2];
              break;
            case 4:
              firstNames[index] =
                nameSplit[0] + " " + nameSplit[1] + " " + nameSplit[2];
              lastNames[index] = nameSplit[3];
              break;

            default:
              firstNames[index] = nameSplit[0];
              lastNames[index] = nameSplit[1];
              break;
          }
        });

        //The change event listeners:
        //When the user click away from the input, and it lost its focus, this event handler will trigger and sets the other input field:
        $("#first_name").on("change", function (e) {
          let fVal = $("#first_name").val();
          let fKey = Object.keys(firstNames).find((k) => firstNames[k] === fVal);
          $("#last_name").val(lastNames[fKey]);
        });

        //It's the same, you can improve this by making a function for it (sry, im lazy):
        $("#last_name").on("change", function () {
          let lVal = $("#last_name").val();
          let lKey = Object.keys(lastNames).find((k) => lastNames[k] === lVal);
          $("#first_name").val(firstNames[lKey]);
        });

        //Source declaration for the datas. Because we use objects in this case, we need only the values.
        $("#first_name").autocomplete({
          source: Object.values(firstNames),
        });
        $("#last_name").autocomplete({
          source: Object.values(lastNames),
        });
      });
    </script>
```